# Angular-translate's localStorage: Unknown provider: $translateLocalStorageProvider

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I'm using [angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate) in my Angular (v1.x) app as well as loading translations from files by using $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader

```
angular.module('myApp',['pascalprecht.translate'])

.config(function($translateProvider) {

     $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader(
          prefix: window.location.pathname.replace(/[\\\/][^\\\/]*$/, '') + '/__languages/',  // absolute path + language path
          suffix: '.json'
     });

     // $translateProvider.useLocalStorage();
}
```

Angular-translate works perfectly but when it comes to use:

```
  $translateProvider.useLocalStorage();
```

(commented in the code above) as proposed in [this guide](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/angular-translate.html), I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $translateLocalStorageProvider <- $translateLocalStorage <- $translate

Of course I included all the the needed js files:

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-translate-loader-url/angular-translate-loader-url.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-translate-loader-static-files/angular-translate-loader-static-files.min.js"></script>
```

I even tried to:

- add **'angular-translate-storage-local'** as a dependency in app.JS
- add **$translateUrlLoader, $translateStaticFilesLoader** in the **.config** block.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have to add `angular-translate-storage-local` as dependency to your app.js file.

I think that you just forgot to include `angular-translate-storage-local` package in your html:

```
 <script src="bower_components/angular-translate-storage-local/angular-translate-storage-local.min.js"></script>
```

[Link to github](https://github.com/angular-translate/bower-angular-translate-storage-local).

Comment: you can install using --> bower install --save angular-translate-storage-local

Comment: In my case I needed to explicitly add all of the following files to get rid of the dependency errors: `angular-cookies`, `angular-translate`, `angular-translate-loader-url`, `angular-translate-loader-static-files`, `angular-translate-storage-local`, `angular-translate-storage-cookie`.